# HTML5 input datetime-local

Tags: html, datetime, input

I used HTML5

```
<input type="datetime-local"` />
```

one of my web pages to allow user to enter a datetime value. This is working fine in Google Chrome. 
But `FireFox(26) and IE(10)` it doesn't. No where it's clearly mentioned the browser compatibility of this HTML5 tag. If anyone know please help me on this.

Thanks

Madhura

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Can I Use is a good resource for checking HTML5 availablility.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime) As of when the question was asked, it shows that date-time inputs are poorly supported outside of Opera and Google Browsers (Chrome, Android).